# Page control content overlay iOS

Tags: ios, overlay, uipageviewcontroller, pagecontrol

I need page control to overlay the content. I am using PageViewController.

[image: expectation]

But page control has personal view below the content.
[image: reality]

How to do this? Thx.

Comment: Build your own view, with a scroll for the element that need to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this lib from github: https://github.com/icepat/ICETutorial